# how to export an excel list into an html list

Tags: javascript, html, excel, list, drop-down-menu

I am trying to find, without success, a code that transform an excel list (from an excel table) into an html list... ( it's a simple table: 4 columns and multiple rows)
I would like to know if it is possible to do so and if yes what is the easiest way to proceed?

I got this code but I don't know how to make it works. Plus it seems in chrome `ActiveXObject` is not supported.
This code, at least, supposes to transfer data from excel to javascript

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <p id='A1'>Test</p> 
 
    <input type='button' onClick='ImportFromXLS_Direct()' value='run' >

    <script>
    
    function ImportFromXLS_Direct() {
    var Path_file;   //  Path_file = "c:/my documents/Excel_export.xls"
    var oExcel;    
    
    var Rep_cour = window.location.href;           
    var Index = Rep_cour.lastIndexOf("/");       
    var Rep_cour = Rep_cour.substring(0,Index);   
    var Path_file = "c:/Desktop/exceltest.xls" // where I have stored my excel file
    
    
    // run EXCEL
    oExcel = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application');
    oExcel.WorkBooks.Open (Path_file);
    oExcel.Sheets("testexc").activate; // name of my sheet
    
    
    // to make EXCEL visible otherwise suppress it
    oExcel.Visible = true;
    
    
 document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = oExcel.ActiveSheet.cells(1,1).value; 
    
    }
    </script>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Just FYI, CSV is a format more portable than XLS which can be exported from excel. This format is easy to be parsed (try to export a CSV file from XLS in excel and open it with a text editor by yourself!). If this change in format is acceptable, the problem can be simplified quite a lot.

Comment: @ SdtElectronics Do You have a tuto , a code how to do this? actually there is an option in excel to transform an excel tab in a webpage.  But the code source in the text editor is messy to use.
Do you suggest to use the code I wrote above with cvs instead?

Comment: CSV files use commas to separate columns and use new lines to represent rows, so ideally you just need to  read the CSV file as String and use `split(",")` and `split("\n")`  to parse it if no excel specific format is applied on your table.

Comment: @ SdtElectronics alright , what is the trick ;-) .... I did what you said and works fine; I have my excel tab into a text separated by ' ; '   but now, how to read/open this `file.txt `  in the js code?

Comment: Hi @ubi, here is a full example: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-Parse-Excel-File-XLS-and-XLSX-using-JavaScript.aspx. Just be sure to load the latest libraries which You can find here: https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs